# How does LogStash handle Redis input restart?

Tags: redis, logstash

I have `Redis v2.4.5` configured as an input for `LogStash v1.2.1`

When `Redis` restarts, `LogStash` continues to keep an open connection (according to `netstat`), but no longer reads messages from the list.

Restarting `LogStash` will fix this problem, but this is not obviously accepted solution in a production scenario.

Is this an expected behaviour ? I was expecting `LogStash` to recover automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this bug have been fixed recently 
https://github.com/logstash/logstash/commit/e6df6a693bee8238751737b646511b227244f932